# TypeScript / Visual Studio 2012 / Compilation parameters

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I need to generate Source Maps when the TypeScript Compiler is executed from Visual Studio 2012. In Sublime Text 2, I just had to add an extra parameter to the build script.
I'm lost in VS 2012.
The Build section doesn't seem to have a section to add build parameters to the build process.

The command switch is "-sourcemap".

As such: tsc -sourcemap file.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a VS 2012 UI for editing the TypeScript build flags (yet) but you can get what you want by editing the project file and adding the `-sourcemap` flag to that build step.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc&quot; -sourcemap @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 5):

Mads Kristensen's Web Essentials extension for Visual Studio added support for producing source maps automatically in version 1.3. You need to enable it in in Tools -> Options for Web Essentials. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6

The free Express editions of Visual Studio does not support extensions.

Comment: Great answer, but this tool doesn't work for VS 2012 Express.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guide on this StackOverflow answer. replace --module amd to --sourcemap.

[Visual Studio TypeScript Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710691/visual-studio-typescript-options)

Answer (score 0):

In 0.9.5 you can use the following:
Upload the project and in the property group and the following tag:

```
<TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
```

That make the job.