# Typescript sourcemaps not loaded in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2012, typescript

I've tried debugging typescript code in chrome which has enabled source maps in chrome. But no sourcemap files are loaded as can be seen in the network tab.

I'm using VS2012 and the latest web essentials package.

Any ideas what to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not see sourcemap files in the network tab. If you go to the Sources tab you will see your typescript files in the list of Sources along the left. From there you can set your breakpoints.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to debug inside VS 2012 you only need to set the breakpoint inside VS and use Internet Explorer when debugging.

[image]

from [Say Hello to TypeScript](https://www.devbridge.com/articles/say-hello-to-typescript/)

If you want to debug in Chrome with sourcemaps make sure that:

1.) they are enabled in Chrome (and you said you did that)

[image]

2.) they are generated by the IDE

You can enable their generation by using `Web Essentials` addon (check above article for details)

or

manually editing the project file's build step: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12730715/750216

**Update:**

It seems that at least in VS Express 2012 for Web sourcemaps are generated automatically by default - no settings needed.